# Jump to errors with logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I develop android apps.

I'm in some confusion about LogCat.

If I sometimes can't Judge where is the error exactly if my app force closes. Is there any way or shortcuts to know where  our error exactly ?

Comment: I need not corrections .. I need answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing the application you should know logcat to know the `error`. It give the complete trace of error. (`Exception name and line no etc.`)

Without understanding logcat you can not make application in android.

Second thing: If you have developed application, distributed in market and user have some problem in your app. For get to know logcat or errors you can use.

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

[Bugsense](http://bugsense.com/)

Comment: can you tell me the use of that two links?

Comment: @Rakesh Naidu  I have written everything in that please read it carefully